# Approach for notifying the user when record is updated

Tags: angular, websocket, architecture, signalr, signalr-hub

We need to notify the user whenever the same record is updated by a different user/system.

My front end is Angular and backend is Asp.Net web API.

I'm thinking of two options

1. poll backend based on timer trigger
2. Signal R to notify the Angular App

Not sure which one is the right fit for this problem. Please recommend.

Comment: This is a bit of an opinion question so might be closed. However, I have good experiences with using SignalR for this. I dislike polling with a vengeance 

Comment: If you control the record update, you could notify the user after successful update.